# Get parent of Json data : Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, twitter-bootstrap, multidimensional-array

```
[
   {
      label:'Priority',
      children:[
         'Total Purchase',
         'Sales',
         [
            {
               label:'Priority',
               children:[
                  'Total Purchase',
                  'Sales'
               ]
            },
            {
               label:'Item',
               children:[
                  'kjashdkaj',
                  'ajshdkj'
               ]
            },
            {
               label:'Region'
            }
         ],

      ]
   },
   {
      label:'Item',
      children:[
         'kjashdkaj',
         'ajshdkj'
      ]
   },
   {
      label:'Region'
   }
]
```

This is the Json data i have. i'm using this to generate a tree structure. i'm able to get the clicked node. but how to get the parent node of any leaf item.

I'm using  [Angular Bootstrap Nav Tree](https://github.com/nickperkinslondon/angular-bootstrap-nav-tree) to generate tree.

Code for defining Tree :

```
<abn-tree 
  tree-data         = "section2lists"
  tree-control      = "section2lists_control"
  on-select         = "section2listitemtree(branch)">      
</abn-tree>
```

and my controller :

```
var salesmodule = angular.module('sales-module',['ui.bootstrap','angularBootstrapNavTree']);

salesmodule.controller('datavisualisation', function ($scope, $uibModal, $log) {
    $scope.section2listitemtree = function (value) {
        $scope.section2lists_return = [value.label];
        var selectedParentBrach = $scope.section2lists_control.get_selected_branch();
        console.log(selectedParentBrach);
    }
});
```

Comment: can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0):

`abnTree` directive does have ability to find the parent branch, If suppose you have below markup

**Markup**

```
<abn-tree 
    tree-data         = "my_treedata"
    tree-control      = "my_tree"
    icon-leaf         = "icon-file"
    icon-expand       = "icon-plus-sign"
    icon-collapse     = "icon-minus-sign"
    on-select         = "my_tree_handler(branch)">      
></abn-tree>
```

Above directive will bind `tree-control` to `my_tree` object (by this object you will have control over rendered tree) and you can find parent branch just by having `get_selected_branch` over tree object.

```
var selectedParentBrach = my_tree.get_selected_branch()
```

[**Directive method here**](https://github.com/nickperkinslondon/angular-bootstrap-nav-tree/blob/master/dist/abn_tree_directive.js#L276)

Comment: but i'm getting my_tree is undefined. Will i have to define it somewhere initially?

Comment: Could you add your directive html here?

Comment: @AmjidBacker could you create plunkr/fiddle?